# Which Beaches in the Canary Islands are Closed Due to the Oleg Naydenov Oil Spill?

Tags: beaches, event-based-effects, canary-islands, environmental-disasters

I am posting this wondering if anyone knows which beaches are now closed if any due to the wreckage of the Oleg Naydenov ship. See this [website](http://www.theguardian.com/world/2015/apr/24/spanish-fuel-oil-spill-russian-oleg-naydenov-gran-canaria) for information about the spill if your wondering.  I will be travelling here soon.  This post can be a running list as this event continues.

Comment: @pnuts You can go ahead and post that as an answer. It definitely helped me and I am sure others who may also utilize this site or search a similar string in google.  This site often comes up in google when people are curious of something and so you should have credit.

Comment: Thanks I went ahead and formulated the answer based on your advice.  The question could be closed if admins feel that it should.  I agree with what you say.

Comment: I'm closing this question because it is not useful for future readers and doesn't require new answers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Apparently there are images of these beaches being polluted with the oil but reports say so far no official closing of the beaches as stated in the other answer of @pnuts

[Tasartico Beach](http://visor.grafcan.es/visorweb/default.php?svc=svcOrtofoto&lat=27.906324003715206&lng=-15.828252761768331&zoom=18&lang=es)

[Guguy Beach](http://visor.grafcan.es/visorweb/default.php?svc=svcOrtofoto&lat=27.945663919020657&lng=-15.827147691654195&zoom=18&lang=es)

[Veneguera Beach](http://visor.grafcan.es/visorweb/default.php?svc=svcOrtofoto&lat=27.846849381347315&lng=-15.791183578967999&zoom=18&lang=es)

[Lo Seco Beach](http://visor.grafcan.es/visorweb/default.php?svc=svcOrtofoto&lat=27.858045557132144&lng=-15.799031722545575&zoom=17&lang=es)

[Tasarte Beach](http://visor.grafcan.es/visorweb/default.php?svc=svcOrtofoto&lat=27.87089442343566&lng=-15.805624357923525&zoom=18&lang=es)

[Meloneras Beach](http://www.eldiario.es/canariasahora/sociedad/pequenas-manchas-fuel-piche-Oleg_Naydenov-costa-Meloneras_0_383562068.html)

and finally there is a video of frustrated citizens trying to clean the beach:
[Youtube Video of Clean Cleaning](https://onthewayfromgrancanaria.wordpress.com/2015/04/30/capitulo-4-oleg-naydenov-la-otra-cara-de-la-tragedia/)

[Daily report (spanish)](http://unidoscontraelfuel.org/?page_id=312)

[Public gallery (need gmail account)](https://plus.google.com/photos/107175401165866642300/albums/6144239440973281073?banner=pwa)

Comment: Fernando, I will combine your answers into this one by editing the answers.  The rest can be deleted after this. Thank you for your primary witness and on the spot reports on this.

Comment: Thanks Daniel. This link show the new of today, there is fuel in Meloneras, near Maspalomas

http://www.eldiario.es/canariasahora/sociedad/pequenas-manchas-fuel-piche-Oleg_Naydenov-costa-Meloneras_0_383562068.html

Comment: I went ahead and added that to the question list.  Thanks again. Feel free to make the edits to this answer yourself as you find more information about the beaches continued pollution or clean up.  I dont mind adding them as i see the more news within the comments but they deserve to be put into the answer itself.

Answer (score 4):

As quoted by @pnuts in the above comments.

> The link has "The regional government of the Canary Islands has not put in place any restrictions on accessing or fishing off the southern beaches of Gran Canaria." ...
>
> Anyway, a better solution for up-to-date information might be to contact admin@ecoturismocanarias.com